# Overlapping Stacked Bar Charts Excel

Tags: excel, graph, charts

I am trying to create an overlapped stacked bar chart. I cannot attach a picture. I have found instructions and examples of stacked bar graphs but none have the overlap that I want.
I will try to explain:

I have two countries A & B for which I collect three series of data in a stacked bar graph.  Each country has actuals and forecast (for the three series).  I would like to overlap actuals and forecasts partially.  The X-axis would like
AF AA (overlapping)  BF BA (overlapping)

What I have found looks like:

AF AA  BF BA.

The bar graphs touch but do not overlap.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I second the Super User suggestion. Also, can you at least post a link to an image. Someone here will edit the post to include the image.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I could not attach a picture because my rating is too low.

Comment: The overlap parameter is already set to 100 in stacked charts so the stacked items are aligned over each other. If you change this you will skew each stacked bar by a greater amount than the bar below. Why do you want to overlap columns anyway? Such overlapping deemphasizes some data by partially hiding it.